# Angular click is not working with input svgs icon

Tags: angular, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind with angular issue is I have svgs icon with my input and its not clickable I try to wrap with div or using cursor-pointer but nothing works.

```
        <div class="mx-2 my-2 align-bottom">
            <label for="search"
                class="mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sr-only dark:text-white">Search</label>
            <div class="relative">
                <div class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-3 pointer-events-none text-secondary">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5"
                        stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                            d="M18.375 12.739l-7.693 7.693a4.5 4.5 0 01-6.364-6.364l10.94-10.94A3 3 0 1119.5 7.372L8.552 18.32m.009-.01l-.01.01m5.699-9.941l-7.81 7.81a1.5 1.5 0 002.112 2.13" />
                    </svg>

                </div>
                <input type="text" [ngModel]="msgText"
                    class="block w-full p-4 pl-10 text-sm text-gray-900 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg bg-inpt-bgcolor"
                    placeholder="Your Message">
                <div class="absolute inset-y-0 right-2.5 flex items-center pr-3 pointer-events-none text-secondary">

                    <div (click)="addMessage()" class="cursor-pointer">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5"
                            stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 ml-2 cursor-pointer">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                                d="M6 12L3.269 3.126A59.768 59.768 0 0121.485 12 59.77 59.77 0 013.27 20.876L5.999 12zm0 0h7.5" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>


                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `class` of the parent-div in the following html-snippet contains `pointer-events-none`, which prevents any clicks from being executed:

```
<div class="absolute inset-y-0 right-2.5 flex items-center pr-3 pointer-events-none text-secondary">
    <div (click)="addMessage()" class="cursor-pointer">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5"
            stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 ml-2 cursor-pointer">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                d="M6 12L3.269 3.126A59.768 59.768 0 0121.485 12 59.77 59.77 0 013.27 20.876L5.999 12zm0 0h7.5" />
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

After I removed `pointer-events-none` it worked:

```
<div class="absolute inset-y-0 right-2.5 flex items-center pr-3 text-secondary">
    <div (click)="addMessage()" class="cursor-pointer">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5"
            stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 ml-2 cursor-pointer">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                d="M6 12L3.269 3.126A59.768 59.768 0 0121.485 12 59.77 59.77 0 013.27 20.876L5.999 12zm0 0h7.5" />
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

Btw: I also found another `pointer-events-none` in the 5th line of your example-code. But maybe this one was intended?:

```
<div class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-3 pointer-events-none text-secondary">
```